# Typescript error ts(2769) in array filter function when in if block that checks for type previously

Tags: typescript, frontend, typescript-typings

I would like to know why typescript complains that `moveInDate` property is possibly `string | undefined` when it is nested inside `if` block that checks whether or not that property is truthy.
In code below you can see that when console logging it is type `string` but when looping an array with `.filter` function it reads it as `string | undefined`.

I know that there is multiple ways of getting around this e.g `new Date(filters.moveInDate!);` or `new Date(filters.moveInDate as string);` . Even defining a new variable `const date = filters.moveInDate` above `.filter` block and then using it inside `.filter` as  `return new Date(date)`. But I want to understand why is this error happening in the first place?

**Code in question**

```
export interface IStateFilters {
  moveInDate?: string;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];

export const filter = (filters: IStateFilters) => {
  if (filters.moveInDate) {
    console.log(filters.moveInDate); // <- it is string over here

    return arr.filter((apt) => {
      return new Date(filters.moveInDate); // why is it string | undefined here?
    });
  }

  return arr;
};
```

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-s7o6f5?file=/index.ts)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73584595/15261914 for the answer. Flagged this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that TypeScript loses the type narrowing when you use filter:

```
export interface IStateFilters {
  moveInDate?: string;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];

export const filter = (filters: IStateFilters) => {
  if (typeof filters.moveInDate === 'undefined') return arr;
  const moveIndate: string = filters.moveInDate;
  return arr.filter((apt: number) => new Date(moveIndate)); // just string now
};
```

Possibly this might help answer it more:

[TypeScript: Why is that my filter method cannot narrow the type and eliminate the undefined and false from the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541843/typescript-why-is-that-my-filter-method-cannot-narrow-the-type-and-eliminate-th)

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069